# React Native alert message

Tags: react-native

new to react native here, so i'm trying to send different alert message when user click on different buttons. But i'm not sure how to do it. Here's my code:

So what will happen is when user click on EXCITED they will receive a alert message and when they click on FINE they will receive another alert message which will say a different thing does anyone  know how to do it?

```
const DATA = [

  {
    id: "1",
    title: "EXCITED",
  },

  {
    id: "2",
    title: "HAPPY",
  },

  {
    id: "3",
    title: "FINE",
  },

  {
    id: "4",
    title: "NOT GOOD",
  },

  {
    id: "5",
    title: "BAD",
  },

];



const Item = ( { item, onPress, style } ) => (

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.item, style]}>

    <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>

  </TouchableOpacity>

);

const Motivation = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {

    const backgroundColor = item.id === selectedId ? "#e6e6e6" : "#F0E6E6";

    return (

      <Item
        item={item}
        onPress={() => setSelectedId(item.id)}
        style={{ backgroundColor }}
      />

    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Alert](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert) by react-native call it using switch for different moods

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

From your above code, I can't see using any FlatList or Data mapping. If you did all that then just import [`Alert`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert) and call it in onPress function like below

```
import {Alert} from 'react-native;
...

  <Item
    item={item}
    onPress={() => {setSelectedId(item.id),Alert.alert(item.title,'your alert message here')}}
    style={{ backgroundColor }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for different type of notification message.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flash-message